# Phone randomly cannot recognize my Wifi network

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-nexus-s

I have a few WiFi network in the neighborhood and the Nexus S will always detect those networks that I never use. However, for my own WiFi network, it randomly fails to recognize the network, even though I sit right next to the router. I know that everything else is OK, because I can access the network through my laptop, and if I just restart the router, the phone will start to pick up the signal again.

I think there might be something wrong with my router, because I never have that problem with the network at work. The only difference I can think of is, I turn off my router right when I stop using WiFi...

What might be wrong? Is this a known bug? Are there workarounds (that does not involve restarting the router?

Update: I do find some clue. If I turn the router on *before* turning on wireless on the phone (via the power management widget), then things work just fine. If I turn on wireless on the phone before the router, I'll need to restart the router. I don't know how much sense it makes though.

Comment: Was this always the case?  This really sounds like your router is just flaky, which we can't help you with ...

Comment: No it's random. And if the problem is with the router, then why don't I have it on my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem. Both the router and the phone was working correctly. The problem is with the Wifi channels. According to Wikipedia's [List of WLAN channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels), some places only allow channels 1-11, some others 1-13. Devices will provide support accordingly. My router supports channels 1-13, while the phone (I guess) supports channels 1-11. So when the router uses channels 12 or 13, the phone cannot detect the network!

Solution?

- Buy another router which only support channels 1-11.
- Logon to your Routers config through your browser to find whether the router supports limiting the channels. Refer to your Routers user manual on how to do this
- Change the channel settings on the router to be manual (i.e not automatic), and somewhere in the range 1-11 (preferably 1 or 6 or 11).