# Phone is finding every wireless access point except mine!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, wi-fi, networking

I have a Samsung Galaxy S using the default firmware (version 2.2).

Unfortunately, it can't seem to find the wireless at work.  When I click "Scan" on the list of WAPs, it continues to appear as a "Remembered" access point rather than connecting.

The laptop is finding the SSID with full bars, so it's just the phone being tetchy.

I've tried rebooting the phone and the router with no change.

Comment: Maybe related to wifi channels http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13015/4403

Comment: another thing that could cause it to not see the network is if the network is using 802.11n. The galaxy s, even though samsung claimed that it supports 802.11n, it does not. If you can switch the AP to use "g" as the "default", you might be able to see the AP.

Comment: @phunehehe: Add as answer (not just comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was indeed Wifi channels (as per phunehehe's comment) - setting the router to use band 11 suddenly brought the access point back into being detectable.  Excellent.

Comment: Note: Only channels 1-11 should be used, using 12 or 13 might render your network "invisible".

Comment: @bigbadonk420: that advice is valid on the US, users on other country should check local regulations on which channels should be used in their country.

Comment: I don't live in the US and networks on 12/13 have disappeared for me multiple times, so I just tend to avoid them.